# Error: bad argument #1 to 'strfind' (string expected, got nil) in Lua

Tags: lua

This is the code:

```
local function scanwhite (str, pos)
  while true do
    pos = strfind (str, "%S", pos)
    if not pos then return nil end
    local sub2 = strsub (str, pos, pos + 1)
    if sub2 == "\239\187" and strsub (str, pos + 2, pos + 2) == "\191" then
      -- UTF-8 Byte Order Mark
      pos = pos + 3
    elseif sub2 == "//" then
      pos = strfind (str, "[\n\r]", pos + 2)
      if not pos then return nil end
    elseif sub2 == "/*" then
      pos = strfind (str, "*/", pos + 2)
      if not pos then return nil end
      pos = pos + 2
    else
      return pos
    end
  end
end
```

I'm not an experienced "scripter" so i can't really figure out how to solve this.

Comment: How do you invoke `scanwhite` ?

Comment: I mean this is a downloaded script that i messed around with a little bit then it told me where the error was. 

https://pastebin.com/qbkmQaqx

There's the whole script.

error is at row 397

Comment: How do you invoke `json.decode`?  Give usage example so that we could reproduce the error.  BTW, there exist other JSON [libraries](https://github.com/Egor-Skriptunoff/json4lua).

Answer (score 0):

### Bottom line up front:

- Problem: 'str' in scanwhite(str, pos) is nil
- Why?

  - You may have written scanwhite() instead of scanwhite("something goes here")
  - You may have passed an empty variable instead of a variable containing a string

### Detailed answer

From the lua 2.4 manual:

```
strfind (str, substr, [init, [end]])
```

- The square brackets mean optional, the ones outside square brackets are mandatory.
- Your error message says *"string expected, got nil"* so a mandatory one was empty
- In your code, substr is clearly not empty (it is "%S")
- By deduction, str was the nil value

Solution:

```
local myString = "This is a string"
scanwhite(mystring)
```